# Find out where a LWC is being used

Tags: lightning-web-components

What are some good ways to quickly find where a Lightning Web Component is being used in Salesforce.

Occasionally I am assigned to modify a LWC but then it takes me some time to find where the component is being used in order to test my changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: In Nov 2022 Robert Strunk wrote a query for the Tooling API:

https://gist.github.com/robertStrunk/580a334651c73ba84f56286835c05533

```
SELECT  MetadataComponentId,
    MetadataComponentName,
    MetadataComponentType,
    RefMetadataComponentId,
    RefMetadataComponentName,
    RefMetadataComponentType
FROM    MetadataComponentDependency
WHERE   RefMetadataComponentType ='LightningComponentBundle'
```

It gets dependencies for all LWCs

Comment: Thank you for providing this, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, you should be able to use the DX command available by installing the [dependencies-cli](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dependencies-cli) plugin, or the [Tooling API query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm). At this time, there's no way to find these dependencies in the UI, as far as I can tell.